# Front end displays 'Only 1 left'... would like it to display 'One of a kind piece' but only for items that have custom attribute one_of_a_kind = Yes

Tags: attributes

I have already create the one_of_a_kind custom attribute

I think I need edit the code in

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/cataloginventory/stockqty/default.phtml
```

I think I could add an if/else statement that would decide (based on whether one_of_a_kind = yes or = no) whether to type 'Only %s left' or simply 'One of a kind piece!'

```
<span class="v-center"
            title="<?php echo $this->__('Only %s left', ($this->getStockQty())) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Only %s left', "<strong>{$this->getStockQty()}</strong>") ?></span>
    </span>
```

However... I don't really know how to refer to the attribute... I don't think the system creates a isOneOfAKind() method or anything, I'm guessing I need to create this method? Where would that method need to be?

I am new to PHP and even newer to Magento and am not really familiar with how it all works but I think I can pull off adding this feature with a point in the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$product->getOneOfAKind();`

Attributes in Magento are retrieved by magic getters, which you don't need to define anywhere. They just work "magically".

You need to remove underscores and capitalize first letter of each segment - like a attribute code `product_attribute_code` would have a getter: `getProductAttributeCode()` that you need to call on the product or whichever relevant product.

Comment: using `getData('product_attribute_code')` is 100% equivalent to the magic `getProductAttributeCode()` and will avoid generating code warnings

Comment: Magento core prefers using: getProductAttributeCode() than getData('product_attribute_code') for the sake of code readability. Which code warnings are you talking about?

Comment: inspection warnings (not interpreter warnings).  Things like: Method 'getHasOptions' not found in class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product 
Referenced method is not found in subject class."

Comment: I don't think either way is wrong; it's just good to know that the magic option and `getData()` are equivalent so you can use whichever you prefer